# What exacly ST_SetSRID in PostGIS does?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, srid

I am new to DBA and PostGIS. I am developing an application using PostgreSQL and PostGIS where nearby locations need to be queried.

I created a sample table as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (geog geography);
```

Inserting like:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (geog)
  VALUES (ST_MakePoint(12.234,23.22));
```

But in some tutorials,insertion is like:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (geog) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-122.079513,45.607703), 4326));
```

I can't clearly understand what `ST_SetSRID` does.
What does it do?
Do I need to use it If I am going to find nearby places, etc?
If I should use it, what value should I go with in the place of `4326` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ST_SetSRID` will set the coordinate reference system of your geometry. This will allow PostGIS commands to understand how your grid will relate to other geometries.

Using `ST_SetSRID` is not essential, as long as all other geometries you may query against are known to be on the same grid. However, if you query against another table that has a SRID set, even if it is known to be of the same grid, PostGIS will fail with a 'mixed geometries' error, which is only resolved when both tables have the same SRID value.

Comment: The OP is using `geography`, which is *implicitly* 4326. While not required, using SRIDs on `geometry` is very much best practice.

Answer (score 7):

With ST_SetSRID it is possible to define explicitly what the coordinates like  `(-122.079513,45.607703)` mean: for example that they are WGS84 long-lat degrees https://epsg.io/4326 and not something else in some other system like https://epsg.io/3857.

As documented for example in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html EPSG:4326 is the default for functions which deal with geography type.

> **Description**
>
> Returns a geography object from the well-known text or
>   extended well-known representation. SRID 4326 is assumed if
>   unspecified. This is an alias for ST_GeographyFromText. Points are
>   always expressed in long lat form.